# App Crashing after changing Photo Settings

Tags: ios, swift

I've got an app that needs access to the Photos on your device. I check to see the device status, and if they deny access I trigger a modal which will warn them that they did not provide the necessary access, and then gives them the option to go to their settings and correct the choice.

When this happens, my app crashes with the following error:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.

Here is my code for triggering the redirect. Any ideas what could be causing this or suggestions on how I should do this better?

```
let title = "You didn't allow us to view your photos!"
let message = "Without access, we cannot help you add photos from your device."
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "I know!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings (Required)", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

    let settingsURL = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(settingsURL!)
}))

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This code is called within a method that I call from the following spot:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status: PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in
    if(status == .Authorized){
        self.getPhonePhotos()
    }else{
        self.showDeniedPhotosPopup()
    }
})
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I just realized something I didn't earlier. The code only crashes if I activate the "Photos" switch in the settings. The navigation itself doesn't cause the app to crash, its changing the photo settings configuration while the app is still running. To test my theory, I never triggered the popup, and simply went to the settings, and activated the photos switch and the app crashed. So the crash is definitely sourcing from the change in photo settings.

Comment: Where you are using this code?

Comment: I call it within a function "showPopup()"

Comment: And where are you calling `showPopup` method?

Comment: Within a class to which I use the Photos API, After I check the authorizationStatus. I've added more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error it appears you are presenting your view controller on a thread which is not main thread leading to implementation of UI stuff (auto layout etc.) on your new view controller on a background thread.

Try encapsulating your view controller presentation code on main queue. Something like this:

```
weak var aBlockSelf = self

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    aBlockSelf.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

If it still crashes, profile your application to find out the exact culprit.

Comment: I added this in and still no luck, though I did realize something this last time. The code only crashes if I activate the "Photos" switch in the settings. The navigation itself doesn't cause the app to crash, its changing the photo settings configuration while the app is still running.